# DataGrid view refreshing from database

Tags: wpf, view, refresh, wpfdatagrid

Hy!
I created a view to populate my datagrid, and I want to update this view and my datagrid. The problem is that in my database the view is refresing but in my form i dont see the changes.

> this.dataGrid.ItemsSource = dataSource.My_View; 
>   My_View.Name = Andy; 
>   My_View.Age = 14; 
>   dataSource.SaveChanges(); 
>   dataGrid.Items.Refresh();

but I do not see this new row in my datagrid, but in database I see this new row.

Can someone help me?
Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not just bind after the update?

```
    My_View.Name = Andy; 
    My_View.Age = 14; 
    dataSource.SaveChanges(); 
    this.dataGrid.ItemsSource = dataSource.My_View;
```